# heroku permission denied on netty start

Tags: scala, heroku, playframework, netty

I have deployed a play scala/java web app on heroku that uses an embeded netty server. The Procfile command is web: target/universal/stage/bin/mmbu-timesheets -Dhttp.port=80

Taken from heroku logs:

```
2015-04-27T13:49:27.160198+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `target/universal/stage/bin/mmbu-timesheets -Dhttp.port=80`
2015-04-27T13:49:29.321552+00:00 app[web.1]: Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Xmx384m -Xss512k -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Djava.rmi.server.useCodebaseOnly=true
2015-04-27T13:49:29.898379+00:00 app[web.1]: Play server process ID is 3
2015-04-27T13:49:32.549840+00:00 app[web.1]: [[37minfo[0m] application - mongodb connection ds031701.mongolab.com:31701 db->heroku_app36286493
2015-04-27T13:49:33.374954+00:00 app[web.1]: [[37minfo[0m] play - Application started (Prod)
2015-04-27T13:49:33.628067+00:00 app[web.1]: Oops, cannot start the server.
2015-04-27T13:49:33.630568+00:00 app[web.1]:    at play.core.server.NettyServer$$anonfun$8.apply(NettyServer.scala:89)
2015-04-27T13:49:33.630523+00:00 app[web.1]:    at play.core.server.NettyServer$$anonfun$8.apply(NettyServer.scala:92)
2015-04-27T13:49:33.630859+00:00 app[web.1]:    at play.core.server.NettyServer$.createServer(NettyServer.scala:206)
2015-04-27T13:49:33.630358+00:00 app[web.1]: org.jboss.netty.channel.ChannelException: Failed to bind to: /0.0.0.0:80
2015-04-27T13:49:33.630483+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.jboss.netty.bootstrap.ServerBootstrap.bind(ServerBootstrap.java:272)
2015-04-27T13:49:33.630606+00:00 app[web.1]:    at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:146)
2015-04-27T13:49:33.630802+00:00 app[web.1]:    at play.core.server.NettyServer.<init>(NettyServer.scala:89)
2015-04-27T13:49:33.630898+00:00 app[web.1]:    at play.core.server.NettyServer$$anonfun$main$3.apply(NettyServer.scala:243)
2015-04-27T13:49:33.630941+00:00 app[web.1]:    at play.core.server.NettyServer$$anonfun$main$3.apply(NettyServer.scala:238)
2015-04-27T13:49:33.631096+00:00 app[web.1]:    at play.core.server.NettyServer$.main(NettyServer.scala:238)
2015-04-27T13:49:33.630975+00:00 app[web.1]:    at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:146)
2015-04-27T13:49:33.631150+00:00 app[web.1]:    at play.core.server.NettyServer.main(NettyServer.scala)
2015-04-27T13:49:33.633017+00:00 app[web.1]: Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Permission denied
2015-04-27T13:49:33.633065+00:00 app[web.1]:    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
2015-04-27T13:49:33.633136+00:00 app[web.1]:    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:437)
2015-04-27T13:49:33.633179+00:00 app[web.1]:    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:429)
2015-04-27T13:49:33.633235+00:00 app[web.1]:    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:223)
2015-04-27T13:49:33.633396+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioServerBoss$RegisterTask.run(NioServerBoss.java:193)
2015-04-27T13:49:33.633444+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioSelector.processTaskQueue(AbstractNioSelector.java:372)
2015-04-27T13:49:33.633550+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioServerBoss.run(NioServerBoss.java:42)
2015-04-27T13:49:33.633600+00:00 app[web.1]:    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
2015-04-27T13:49:33.633643+00:00 app[web.1]:    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
2015-04-27T13:49:33.633305+00:00 app[web.1]:    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:74)
2015-04-27T13:49:33.633525+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioSelector.run(AbstractNioSelector.java:296)
2015-04-27T13:49:33.633703+00:00 app[web.1]:    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
2015-04-27T13:49:34.926567+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 255
2015-04-27T13:49:34.945535+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
```

I get "Permission denied" exception. Is there a way to start the netty server in heroku?

Answer (score 4):

I had to let heroky specify the port with

```
web: target/universal/stage/bin/mmbu-timesheets -Dhttp.port=$PORT
```

in Procfile